# Keeps internal links when printing webpage to PDF

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

I am working with Chrome (up to date)

I would like to export a webpage to PDF (via print) and keep internal links like :

```
<a href="#Section1">Section 1</a>
```

For now it seems to keep the "a" tag because the element is clickable, but clicking on it doesn't do anything.

It is even possible ?

Comment: Since Firefox 90 (May 2021) the Firefox print functionality prints (absolute external) links in general into a PDF document [source: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/print-to-pdf-preserving-hyperlinks/23844/27 ]. "Internal links" still do not seem to work. I just created a ticket (before I found yours): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76193983/print-html-to-pdf-with-document-internal-links-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

In my own testing of a fresh Chrome download, viewing an HTML page that uses internal links ([this one](https://www.access-board.gov/guidelines-and-standards/communications-and-it/about-the-section-508-standards/section-508-standards) from the United States Access Board on some technical standards), I found that it offers a "Save as PDF" option on its Print menu (select the Change... button, and find the first option under the Local Destinations subhead), and that does emit a PDF file with working internal links.

I should add that I'm not *100%* certain that it came with Chrome, because all my test machines have Acrobat installed as well, but I don't see the same entry in the Print menu of my IE browsers, so I believe "Save as PDF" is an actual Chrome feature, and not just an Acrobat plug-in.

There are also various other products out there offering HTML-to-PDF conversions, including those that specifically promise to preserve internal links, so if you chose one that installed as a Print driver, you could then have that same full-featured HTML-to-PDF capability in any browser, not just Chrome, by simply picking that conversion tool from your printer menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact I am using this Chrome feature to save my HTML to PDF. But internal links are not working...

Comment: Okay, can you tell if it matters which HTML page you are saving, in terms of perhaps sometimes the links work and sometimes they do not? Can you upload a link to a page that you are testing? Were you able to test the page that I linked above?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Even in 2022, it didn't work with Firefox, so I doubted that I would work in Chrome. However, you are right. Using Chrome, just opened https://www.japheth.de/JWasm/Manual.html and saved it as PDF, and all links are working internally. What a blessing ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pdf-converter built into LibreOffice Writer. I have had good results with that, including working internal links.

1. Save the page as html
2. Open the saved html file in LibreOffice Writer
3. Tweak the layout, remove unwanted sidebars, etc.
4. Export to pdf.

This has the added advantage that you get the chance to tweak your results in step 3 to avoid things, like lines only filling about half the page width, that often occur when directly printing from the browser.

A possible drawback may be that this could fail for websites that are dynamically generated so they don't save well as html. I have not had the desire to print/convert one of those pages yet though.