# Print HTML to PDF with document internal links in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

When I open the following HTML document in Firefox / Chromium and then print it (by pressing Ctrl + P), then the links behave different.

The links in the PDF printed with Chromium are document internal links. This is what I want and the following screenshot shows is how it looks like:

[image: Link printed with Chromium]

The links in the PDF printed with Firefox are document external (absolute) links to the site where I printed the document at. (The result is the same whether I start the print manually with Ctrl+P or by calling window.print()) This is not what I want and the following screenshot shows how it looks like:

[image: Link printed with Firefox]

How can I give the Firefox browser to behave in the same way like the Chromium does (to generate PDF-document internal links)?

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <a href="#target1">To target 1</a>
    <a href="#target2">To target 2</a>
    <div style="height:100vh;background-color:green">Some space</div>
    <div id="target1">This is target 1<div>
    <div style="height:100vh;background-color:yellow">Some more space</div>
    <div id="target2">This is target 2</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```